# Indexing the values of the List

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two different lists with almost the same values but with different index values. I have some values in `list_1` and need to extract index of those values in `list_2`.
Then I want to combine `list_1` as `['Number']` column and index outcome as `['Index']` column in a Dataframe.

```
list_1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
list_2 = ['12','11','10','9','8','6','5','4','3','2','1']
data = {"Number":pd.Series(list_1)}
df = pd.Dataframe(data,columns=["Number"])
list_index=[]
for i in df["Number"]:
    if i in list_2:
       index= pd.Index(list_2)
       m = index.get_loc(i)
       list_index.append(m)
df['Index']=list_index
```

Error is that quantity of values in `df["Number"]` and `list_index` are different.

But when I'm trying to add `list_1` and m to DataFrame, I can't assign all the dedicated indices to the numbers in `list_1`.

Comment: Can you provide an exemple output. Are you not confused between list index and list element?

Comment: ValueError: Length of values (9) does not match length of index (11)

Comment: you do not have `7` in `list_2` and that's why you get the `length error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you find the indices of elements in `list_2`:

```
indices = [list_2.index(l) if l in list_2 else None for l in list_1]
```

I set `None` when an element is not present in your `list_2` but you can put whatever value you desire.

Then, you form the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': list_1, 'Index': indices})
```

Output:

```
    Number  Index
0   1   10.0
1   2   9.0
2   3   8.0
3   4   7.0
4   5   6.0
5   6   5.0
6   7   NaN
7   8   4.0
8   9   3.0
9   10  2.0
```